# Decode UTF-8 encoded Cyrillic with Delphi 2007

Tags: delphi, unicode, indy, google-analytics-api

I am working in Delphi 2007 (no Unicode support) and I am retrieving XML and JSON data from the Google Analytics API. Below is some UTF-8 encoded data that I get for a URL referral path:

> ga:referralPath=/add/%D0%9F%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BC

When I decode it using [this decoder](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) it properly generates this:

> ga:referralPath=/add/Пижам

Is there a function I can use in Delphi 2007 which will perform this decoding?

**UPDATE**
This data is corresponds to a URL.  Ultimately what I want to do is to store this in a SqlServer database (out of the box - no settings modified regarding character sets).  And then be able to produce/create an html pages with a working link to this page (note: I am only dealing with the url referral path in this example - obviously to make a valid url link a source would be needed).

Comment: Then why not just store the original encoded URL as-is instead of decoding it?

Comment: Yes - that is what ultimately what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

D2007 supports Unicode, just not to the extent that D2009+ does.  Unicode in D2007 is handled using `WideString` and the few RTL support functions that do exist.

The URL contains percent-encoded UTF-8 byte octets.  Simply convert those sequences into their binary representation and then use `UTF8Decode()` to decode the UTF-8 data to a `WideString`.  For example:

```
function HexToBits(C: Char): Byte;
begin
  case C of
    '0'..'9': Result := Byte(Ord(C) - Ord('0'));
    'a'..'f': Result := Byte(10 + (Ord(C) - Ord('a')));
    'A'..'F': Result := Byte(10 + (Ord(C) - Ord('A')));
  else
    raise Exception.Create('Invalid encoding detected');
  end;
end;

var
  sURL: String;
  sWork: UTF8String;
  C: Char;
  B: Byte;
  wDecoded: WideString;
  I: Integer;
begin
  sURL := 'ga:referralPath=/add/%D0%9F%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BC';
  sWork := sURL;
  I := 1;
  while I <= Length(sWork) do
  begin
    if sWork[I] = '%' then
    begin
      if (I+2) > Length(sWork) then
        raise Exception.Create('Incomplete encoding detected');
      sWork[I] := Char((HexToBits(sWork[I+1]) shl 4) or HexToBits(sWork[I+2]));
      Delete(sWork, I+1, 2);
    end;
    Inc(I);
  end;
  wDecoded := UTF8Decode(sWork);
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Gives "Operator not applicable to this operand type" compile error on **C - Ord('0');**

Comment: Got it to compile by converting casting references of **C** with **ord(C)**

Comment: I'd prefer ord(C-'0') FWIW

Comment: Huh. In my head I thought you could perform arithmetic on character types. Apparently not.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: in C/C++, character types support arithmetic.  In Delphi, they do not.

Comment: @Remy Indeed. I really ought to know that. Funny how one can know some things and be hopeless in other areas.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - seeing you fail at these things works wonders for my self esteem, thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code, which uses Windows API :

```
function Utf8ToStr(const Source : string) : string;
var
  i, len : integer;
  TmpBuf : array of byte;
begin
  SetLength(Result, 0);
  i := MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, @Source[1], Length(Source), nil, 0);
  if i = 0 then Exit;
  SetLength(TmpBuf, i * SizeOf(WCHAR));
  Len := MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, @Source[1], Length(Source), @TmpBuf[0], i);
  if Len = 0 then Exit;

  i := WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, @TmpBuf[0], Len, nil, 0, nil, nil);
  if i = 0 then Exit;

  SetLength(Result, i);
  i := WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, @TmpBuf[0], Len, @Result[1], i, nil, nil);
  SetLength(Result, i);
end;
```

Comment: Converting to ANSI is dubious at best. Surely you want to stick to Unicode.

Comment: Using unicode is better idea for sure. But M Schenkel seems to need ANSI output.

Comment: That's not clear to me. Anyway, UTF8Decode is much simpler to use than your code, and simple WideString -> string assignment does UTF16 -> ANSI

Comment: This code first converts utf-8 encoded data, stored in string (actually, to make code clear, input should be array of byte), to utf-16. And after that - utf-16 to ANSI code page.

Comment: I know what the code does, I'm telling you that it is needlessly complex. Your entire answer can be compressed into two lines of code.

Comment: Surely, it can be compressed, but I forgot that UTF8Decode() works in D2007.